# Android java.lang.IllegalStateExecption: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using a book to make a very simple "Hello World" app but when I run it and I attempt to click the button to call a method I am receiving the below info in my LogCat

```
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18784)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    ... 11 more
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.Hello}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1647)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.helloworld.MainActivity.helloload(MainActivity.java:20)
03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    ... 14 more
```

This is my method with with line 20 being the last line.

```
public void helloload (View view)    {
Intent helloload = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hello.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(helloload);

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define Hello Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

check the below part of your catlog:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.Hello}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 03-02 09:31:17.032: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):
```

Answer (score 2):

As the Error Log clearly says

You have not declared the activity in your androidmanifest.xml

add the following line of code in your androidmanifest.xml under application tag to make it work

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.helloworld.Hello"
        android:label="@string/hello world" >
    </activity>
```

where com.helloworld is the package name where your activity is created